# Granted "Alter Server State" but can't run DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS

Tags: sql-server, permissions, sql-server-2019

The documentation says that, for SQL Server, DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS needs the following permissions:

> Requires ALTER SERVER STATE permission on the server

Yet when I am granted that, I still don't have permissions to run DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS.

I get:

```
User 'MyLoginHere' does not have permission to run DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS.
```

Are there other, hidden permissions needed to grant permissions to run this?

Answer (score 4):

I suspect this is a bug rather than a documentation issue since it works in SQL Server 2022. I successfully ran the script below in SQL 2022 but it fails in older versions with "User 'guest' does not have permission to run DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS.".

```
USE master;
CREATE LOGIN Repro WITH PASSWORD='sdfI#(#8403';
GRANT ALTER SERVER STATE TO Repro;
GO
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'Repro'
GO
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS;
GO
REVERT;
GO
```

A work-around to allow less privileged users to execute `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS` is to wrap the command in a proc and sign it based on a certificate login with the needed permissions. This method is better than granting `ALTER SERVER STATE` if only `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS` is needed. See Erland's [Packaging Permissions in Stored Procedures](https://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html) article for a complete discussion of this technique.

```
USE master;
CREATE CERTIFICATE sysadmin_cert
   ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '<encryption-password>'
   WITH SUBJECT = 'Confer sysadmin privileges';
GO
-- Create a login for the certificate.
CREATE LOGIN sysadmin_cert_login FROM CERTIFICATE sysadmin_cert;
ALTER SERVER ROLE sysadmin
    ADD MEMBER sysadmin_cert_login;
GO
CREATE PROC dbo.usp_DROPCLEANBUFFERS
AS 
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS;
GO
ADD SIGNATURE TO dbo.usp_DROPCLEANBUFFERS BY CERTIFICATE sysadmin_cert WITH PASSWORD='<encryption-password>';
GO
CREATE USER Repro; --in master database
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.usp_DROPCLEANBUFFERS TO Repro;
GO
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'Repro'
GO
EXECUTE dbo.usp_DROPCLEANBUFFERS;
GO
REVERT;
GO
```